# How to bind a tooltip on table cells with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, material-design-lite

I have a table generated with Vue.js over `items`.

I bound `item.id` with html's `id` and `for` attributes to display a tooltip with [MDL](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#tooltips-section) but this one is not showing.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
<div id="items">
    <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Status
                </th>
                <th>
                    Name    
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>                
            <tr v-for="item in items">
                <td>
                    <i v-if="item.isActive" class="material-icons" style="color:#4CAF50">power_settings_new</i>
                    <i v-else class="material-icons" style="color:#F44336">power_settings_new</i>
                </td>

                <!-- HERE -->
                <td v-bind:id="item.id">

                    {{ item.shortName }}

                    <!-- v-bind working but tooltip is not showing. -->
                    <div class="mdl-tooltip mdl-tooltip--large" v-bind:for="item.id">
                        {{ item.name }}
                    </div>
                </td>                   
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I also tried to bind on div rather than td, sadly it's not working too.

```
                <div v-bind:id="item.id">
                    {{ item.shortName }}
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-tooltip mdl-tooltip--large" v-bind:for="item.id">
                    {{ item.name }}
                </div>
```

Comment: please note that in the first row of your HTML you did not use the closing quotes for the div identified as "items".

Comment: Edited. Thanks !

Comment: Did you try to bind id to data-mdl-for instead of v-bind:for? I don't understand why, in MDL documentation, the large tooltip is bound to "for" while the small one is bound to "data-mdl-for".

Comment: I just tried, but it's not working too... Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the Material Design Lite library, but I'm guessing this probably has to do with the fact that your elements are being generated dynamically by Vue, and the MDL library scans the DOM and configures your components on page load only:

> Material Design Lite will automatically register and render all elements marked with MDL classes upon page load. However in the case where you are creating DOM elements dynamically you need to register new elements using the `upgradeElement` function.

MDL and Vue don't play well together; you're going to have to tell MDL about any dynamic DOM changes manually in code, for example:

```
var button = document.createElement('button');
var textNode = document.createTextNode('Click Me!');
button.appendChild(textNode);
button.className = 'mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect';
componentHandler.upgradeElement(button);
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(button);
```

See [Use MDL on dynamic websites](https://getmdl.io/started/index.html#dynamic) for more information.

---

This is completely untested, but maybe you can write a Vue directive that will allow you to call `updateElement` on new DOM elements:

```js
Vue.directive('mdl-element', {
  update(el) {
    componentHandler.upgradeElement(el)
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="mdl-tooltip mdl-tooltip--large" v-bind:for="item.id" v-mdl-element>
```

I'm not even sure if `upgradeElement` can be called multiple times on the same element, and `upgradeElement` might replace the element entirely with something else which really isn't going to play nice with Vue, but you get the idea.